# Função JSON Não retorna valor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

tenho um problema, gostaria de popular meu DropDownlistFor com o resultado de um outro DropDownListFor, para isso estou utilizando Ajax e Json, mesmo conceito que fazem quando querem o resultado de Estado para Cidade.

```
Model:

    public class SegmentMOD
        {
            public int id { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Segmento")]
            public string nome { get; set; }
        }
            public class SectorMOD
        {
            public int id { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Setor")]
            public string nome { get; set; }

            public int segmentId { get; set; }
        }

Controller:

    OpportunityController: Controller
    {

    public ActionResult Cadastrar()
            {
                //Aqui funciona normal, retorna os valores
                ViewBag.segmentList = new SelectList(new SegmentREP().ListarTodos(),
                    "id",
                    "nome"
                );

                return View();
            }
            //vai preencher o Where com o Id do segment
            public async Task<JsonResult> CarregarSector(int id)
        {
            var setor = new SectorREP().ListarTodos().Where(x => x.segmentId ==id);

            return Json(setor, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }

View:

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Cadastrar";
    }

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#segment").change(function () {
            listaCidade($(this).val());
        });
    });

    //chamada ajax para a Action ListaCidade
    //passando como parâmetro a Estado selecionado
    function listaCidade(segmentId) {
        //Chamando o metodo do controller para retornar um JSON
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Opportunity/CarregarSector',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: segmentId },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#sector").empty();
                $(result).each(function () {
                    //adicionando as opções de acordo com o retorno
                    $("#sector").append("<option value='" + this.id + "'>" + this.nome + "</option>");
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Erro! Não foi possível carregar os Setores.');
            }
        });

    }
</script>



        <h2>Cadastrar</h2>


                                                <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.segment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.segment, (SelectList)ViewBag.segmentList, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker show-tick", data_live_search = "true", id = "segment" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.segment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                            <select class="form-control" id="sector"></select>

                        </div>
```

Comment: Você já testou o Ajax chamando ele manualmente?

Comment: Como seria isso ?

Comment: [Usando isto](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).

Comment: Vou tentar usar a ferramenta mais se tiverem a solução agradeço.

Comment: Então, mas eu preciso saber mais coisas pra poder te responder. O Ajax estar de acordo é uma delas. Depois vou olhar o restante que você colocou. Apenas com isso não consigo te dizer o que é.

Comment: Estou testando mais sem sucesso preciso de outra alternativa, mais vou tentando nesse tempo.

Comment: Faça o seguinte: faça o JSON devolver resultado usando GET, não POST. Como é somente leitura o que você está fazendo, evite colocar complicações desnecessárias.

Comment: Ele traz um resultado assim.   CarregaSector?id=2; eu gostaria de saber o resultado do (result), mais ele da erro e executa o  error: Function()

Comment: Bom, então dá erro mesmo. O console JS devolve alguma coisa? O código no ASP.NET dá erro?

Comment: O código asp.net não devolve erro e o console JS apenas (id=2) não devolve nada também.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CarregaSector (int id)
        {
            return Json (new SectorREP().ListarTodos().Where(x => x.segmentId == id));
        } esse ID de retorno(id=2) e para completar meu Where, e o result seria  esse return(return Json), acima, será que este formato que estou retornando esta correto ?

Comment: Falei pra você fazer o teste sem o [HttpPost]. Por que ainda não foi feito?

Comment: Eu Fiz, não percebi diferença.

Comment: Amigos, Estou precisando de ajuda pois não tenho uma solução... Obrigado a todos e agradeço muito ao Cigano Morrison, pela ajuda até o momento.

Comment: Cigano, consegui imprimir o valor na tela do Json passando o ID, na url na mão mesmo, agora queria pegar e passar o ID do DropDownlist e passar como parâmetro do método para listar os setores, o sucess: do ajax que da erro.

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta e colocar como está o código até então?

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Model:

        public class SegmentMOD
            {
                public int id { get; set; }

                [DisplayName("Segmento")]
                public string nome { get; set; }
            }
                public class SectorMOD
            {
                public int id { get; set; }

                [DisplayName("Setor")]
                public string nome { get; set; }

                public int segmentId { get; set; }
            }

    Controller:

        OpportunityController: Controller
        {

        public ActionResult Cadastrar()
                {
                    //Aqui funciona normal, retorna os valores
                    ViewBag.segmentList = new SelectList(new SegmentREP().ListarTodos(),
                        "id",
                        "nome"
                    );

                    return View();
                }
                //vai preencher o Where com o Id do segment
                public async Task<JsonResult> CarregarSector(int id)
            {
                var setor = new SectorREP().ListarTodos().Where(x => x.segmentId ==id);

                return Json(setor, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }

    View:

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Cadastrar";
        }

            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#segment").change(function () {
                listaSector($(this).val());
            });
        });

        //chamada ajax para a Action CarregarSector
        //passando como parâmetro o Segmento selecionado
        function listaSector(segmentId) {
            //Chamando o metodo do controller para retornar um JSON
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Opportunity/CarregarSector',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id: segmentId },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#sector").empty();
                    $(result).each(function () {
                        //adicionando as opções de acordo com o retorno
                        $("#sector").append("<option value='" + this.id + "'>" + this.nome + "</option>");
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Erro! Não foi possível carregar os Setores.');
                }
            });

        }
    </script>



            <h2>Cadastrar</h2>


                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.segment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.segment, (SelectList)ViewBag.segmentList, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker show-tick", data_live_search = "true", id = "segment" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.segment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                <select class="form-control" id="sector"></select>

                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução seria você gerar o código html direto na controller.

```
 //Gera options do selectlist
  StringBuilder strHtml = new StringBuilder();
  strHtml.Append("<option value='0'>Selecione...</option>");
  foreach ( var sector in sectorList )
  {
       //Para cada resultado encontrado gera uma option para o selectlist
       strHtml.AppendFormat("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", sector.id, sector.nome);
  }
       //retorna html referente ao selectlist sector
       return Json(new { options = strHtml.ToString() });
```

E no retorno da função ajax dar o append das opções no respectivo  select.

```
 success: function (result) {
            $("#sector").empty();
            $("#sector").html(result.options);
        },
```